# progress 4gl - forms and frames

Tags: forms, frame, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4gl. I am stuck up with the concept of frames and forms.

Can anyone please explain the ***usage of form and frame** in **progress 4gl*** with a an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A frame is a collection of stuff that you want to display.  There are implicit unnamed frames associated with the procedure and with iterating blocks.

Or you can explicitly create a frame with DEFINE FRAME.

You can also create named frames using the WITH FRAME phrase in many statements.  One such statement is the FORM statement.  FORM statements are handy for organizing the layout of a frame in one place (often at the top of a program).  Later in the program UPDATE, DISPLAY and other statements may reference the FRAME described by the FORM as they do their work.

Event driven code (GUI stuff) often qualifies references to widgets (controls) and events by specifying which frame they are associated with.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a frame can not start it's scope while Form started the scope of that frame.